# Написание своей CMS

Tags: jquery, php, cms, mysql

Всем добрый день задумался о написании своей CMS.

Но толком не знаю с чего начинать.

Какие основные функции и элементы обязательно должны быть в хорошей CMS?
Какие проверки должны быть до того как страницу сайта увидит пользователь?

Comment: Просто скопируйте вашу любимую cms.

Comment: У меня нет любимой CMS я их все терпеть не могу .... Поэтому и хочу написать свою

Comment: глупый вопрос, наверное, но для чего вы решили ее написать, если не знаете, что в ней должно быть?

Comment: >Просто скопируйте вашу любимую cms

и получится BolgenCMS

Comment: @DreamChild я имел ввиду не ctrl+c :D

Comment: >У меня нет любимой CMS я их все терпеть не могу

А с каким CMS вы работали и как глубоко знаете архитектуру?

Comment: вообще возьмите любую cms на github и просто добавьте к ней нужный вам функционал, делайте pull request и ненавидимая cms превратится в любимую.

Comment: И всё таки поддержу мнение большинства - нужно быстро сделать сайт, делайте на фреймворках. Они тоже не стоят на месте и постоянно модифицируются. Лично у меня ушло около месяца на изучение Yii. Решил переписать свой старый сайт, кстати, считаю такой способ лучшим в изучении любого FW или CMS.

Comment: почему велостроители так любят CMS ? есть куда более интересные направления.

Answer (score 2):

Просто не нужно изобретать велосипед. почему я так написал? Потому, что вы не имеете представления, что хотите написать.

На мой взгляд хорошая CMS это та CMS которая удовлетворяет все потребности пользователя. Если вы такую создадите вас ждет успех.

Для начала я думаю вам стоит провести анализ рынка CMS. Выявить все сильные и слабые стороны текущих CMS. Узнать потребности пользователей. Определить (угадать) будущие тренды в этом направлении для того , чтобы когда вы напишите вашу CMS не получилось так, что она никому не нужна.

Успехов!

Comment: Ну собственно мне не для пользователей CMS нужна а для создания быстрых и правильных сайтов. Я не говорю об админке и ее функциях там и тд меня интересует сам процесс компиляции страниц что необходимо учесть какие проверки нужно сделать какими функциями обрабатывать все вот что мне нужно знать ...

Comment: создать свою хорошую cms вы сможете после того как разберетесь как работаю самые популярные и признанные cms.

Comment: я бы вам порекомендовал изучить framework например symfony 2 или еще какой (к сожалению на php не пишу) и на базе этого fw  уже делать сайты. Как правило в таких fw уже многое сделано за вас.

Comment: На изучение framework ковыряния в его исходном коде к сожалению времени совсем нет. Неужели нет такого материала где бы четко и ясно было написано основные элементы CMS такие то такие то. С использованием таких то таких то функций для того того и того ??

Comment: если у вас нет времени на изучение fw то времени на написание того, что вы хотите у вас к сожалению тоже не будет. Что касается элементов CMS и компонентов то вы можете зайтв в документацию любой более менее приличной CMS там как правило все описано как концептуально так и в деталях, что для чего и зачем. Тут вряд ли ктото вам будет расписывать. 

Например, Bitrix.ru http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/docs/php.php все прям по блокам разбито бери и читай.

Comment: @alexsis20102, если бы вы достаточно хорошо знали, как пишутся крупные сайты на php, подобных вопросов бы не возникало. CMS пишется для людей, плохо знакомых с программированием. Люди хорошо знающие php и ООП пишут на фреймворках, а это совсем другой уровень.

Comment: Я прекрасно знаю ООП Модель MVC но скажу раз ты такой умный вот пиши и наслаждайся на своих дырявых фреймворках. Я написал тут вопрос на который хочу получить ответ а не выслушивать какие либо упреки в сторону моих знаний или же чего либо другого. И CMS пишется не для людей плохо знакомых с программированием а мое личное мнение для простоты и скорости создания сайтов. Попрошу боле не писать такие комментарии.

Comment: @alexsis20102, если вы до сих пор не получили ответа который бы вас удовлетварил может стоит задуматься над вопросом?

Comment: Я получил ответ для себя. Он заключается в том что никто походу не знает и не задумывался над тем что необходимо в хорошей и качественной CMS. А если кто то и знает то он попросту не скажет. Так что придется искать все как всегда самому.

Comment: Битрикс в пример не надо ставить не делайте так как там.

Comment: @alexsis20102 '... Неужели нет такого материала где бы четко и ясно было написано о ... таких то функций для того того и того .."
на сайты этих самых CMS не пробовали заходить? К примеру у WordPress целый кодекс написан http://codex.wordpress.org/Main_Page

Comment: @zippp, да, ворпдресс это идеальная CMS, если начинать заниматься CMSками. Её функциональности, хотя бы наполовину сделать и уже будет счастье.

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужен инструмент создания сайта, а не система управления контентом, то это о фреймворках. Их достаточно, от простых до сложных, выбирайте любую: Yii, Symphony, Kohana и т.д.